# IOS remove space between each tab bar item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Here is my tab bar:

[image]

I want to make tab bar like design below:

[image]

Title of tab bar item is nil (words inside image). My code in tab bar class below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:67/255.0 green:67/255.0 blue:67/255.0 alpha:1];
    for (UITabBarItem *tbi in self.tabBar.items) 
    {
        tbi.title = nil;
        tbi.image = [tbi.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        tbi.selectedImage = [tbi.selectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        tbi.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6.0, 0.0, -6.0, 0.0);
    }
}
```

I tried with many size for tab bar item but it not change. Please help me to solve this issue
Thank so much!

Comment: I think you want to  try custom tab bar use.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is right. `imageInsets` do change the size and position of tabbaritem.image. it's works fine in my project.

maybe `tbi.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0);` is better with your condition.

if your text and image is too close, you should adjust the image itself cause your text is with your images

Answer (score -1):

your code is right

you can get particular item of tab bar and try to set diffrent Insets like

```
 // UIEdgeInsets insets = {top, left, bottom, right};  

 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
     UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
         UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
    tabBarItem1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0);
    tabBarItem2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0);
    tabBarItem3.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0);
   tabBarItem4.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-6.0, -6.0, -6.0, -6.0);
```